# Postgresql - update column even if value is too long

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I have this query:

```
begin    
    update res_partner_address rpa
    set name = rp.name
    from res_partner rp
    where rpa.partner_id = rp.id
    and rpa.name is NULL
end;
```

When I try to update that column, I get this error:

```
ERROR:  value too long for type character varying(64)
```

So `name` and `rp.name` differ in maximum length. Is there a way to truncate value to `name`'s length, so I could update it anyway?

Comment: cast(rp.name as character varying(64))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use the first 64 characters from the res_partner table:

```
update res_partner_address rpa
  set name = left(rp.name,64)
from res_partner rp
where rpa.partner_id = rp.id
and rpa.name is NULL
```